# Release error is coming Check for errors on the Permissions Declaration Form (play store error)

Tags: java, android, google-play-console, runtime-permissions

It is showing this error
[image]

here is my permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

And I have done the dynamic permission thing. Still, I am getting this error.

Comment: do you had ask permission at runtime

Comment: Yes, I have released the build 5 days back with same permission. That is available at play store right now but today I am getting this. I do not know why.

Comment: I'm having the same problem today.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue @NateNiemi

Comment: @PiyushUpadhyay Nope, not sure what happened. No changes to manifest. It worked yesterday. Odd coincidence we both just noticed this problem today.

Comment: I'm having the same problem no changes in permission, maybe some bug in Play Console?

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Glad I'm not alone. I put in a support request to google. We will see what they say.

Comment: i have same error here and in my app i did not add any permission ...

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same error right now... incremented build and untouched permissions..

Comment: Glad I am not alone.

Comment: Same here... at first I thought it was because today was my first time submitting the app using their API, but after that failed (with a similar message) I tried to submit it manually through the Google Play Console website and I'm seeing the same error. Don't see the permissions form though, not even after retrying to submit.

Comment: Everything is now working for me. I made no changes to anything. I think this confirms it was a bug on Google's end.

Comment: Guys. I solved the problem. First check if you have your APK in beta or alpha with the non-permitted permissions. If you do, create a new release and upload to alpha then beta and finally production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now confirm this issue is fixed as of Jan 26, 2019 Asia Pacific Time.

Comment: Same here. No changes, just created a new build (to increment the version code) and submitted that successfully on Jan 28 2019.

Comment: Just received a response from Google. Hi there,

Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support.

I understand your Play Console wants you to fill out a permissions form, though you haven't added any new permissions.  This issue was affecting a number of developers, but I have received word this morning that the issue was corrected.  You should be able to upload an update APK as normal (please note you may need to first discard any existing drafts).

I hope that helps! Please let me know if you have other questions.

Regards,
Pete
Google Play Developer Support

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem this way. You might have an APK (alpha, beta or prod) with the non-permitted permissions.

- Step1: create a new release without the non-permitted permissions
- Step2: roll it over to Alpha
- Step3: roll it over to Beta
- Step4: roll it over to Production

Greetings!

Comment: I tried everything but this, and this is the only working solution. If I try to publish to beta without publishing to alpha, I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is currently affecting users who removed SMS and CALL_LOG from their app due to the new policy and also submitted the form. From yesterday these apps fails to update for the above error without giving any solution within the UI due to the fact that the app doesnt have those permissions anymore. Its clearly a bug in the store. I've tried via API and off course getting the same result:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "androidpublisher",
    "message" : "Permission declaration is invalid because the declaration has not been accepted in the Play Console.",
    "reason" : "permissionDeclarationNotAccepted"
  } ],
  "message" : "Permission declaration is invalid because the declaration has not been     accepted in the Play Console."
}
```

I have a pipeline currently triggering each hour to see if this goes away. Its already more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I too am getting this Error message.  Submitted a build this morning, no issues.  No permissions added, and no strange permissions.  I suggest everyone impacted submit feedback to Google via the link below!

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing

Comment: I have actually heard from my google rep - they are aware and on the issue ASAP!

Comment: Great news... I did not yet hear from them after submitting the yesterday..

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error.

My app has quite ordinary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Seems like an issue from Google's side. Submitted yesterday with no issue. Starting facing this issue today only.

Answer (score 0):

It's already well answered by FrankMonza in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54367452/1004836.

For some still having a problem with this issue, try to update the APK(s) which currently resides on another channel. We have an outdated APK in the Alpha channel. After we updated it to the latest APK, we are then able to propagate it through Beta, then Production.